# Subtables not showing in List of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

In my list of tables I can see the tables that begin with:

```
\begin{longtable}
```

But the tables that have subtables in the following way simply does not appear in the list of tables:

```
\begin{table}[hbp!]

     \begin{subtable}
     \end{subtable}

     \begin{subtable}
     \end{subtable}

\end{table}
```

This is the piece of code in the .cls file that generates the list of tables:

```
\newpage
    \iftablespage
            \addvspace{10pt}
            \listoftables
            \newpage
    \fi
```

I tried with `\setcounter{lotdepth}{3}` but it shows "No counter lotdepth defined."

How can I make the list of tables to show the subtables?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please make your code snippets compilable ... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Which package do you load to provide a `subtable` environment?

Answer (score 1):

After trying with pieces of code from semi related questions, the thing that worked for me was simply to add:

```
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
```

Comment: This post could really benefit from an example that visitors can relate to. Can you add a minimal example to your question (or at least, to this answer)?